# root не может записать в файл, принадлежащий другому пользователю

Tags: linux, ubuntu, libc

обнаружил вот такое интересное поведение:

```
root@host~# touch /tmp/some.file
root@host~# chown nobody /tmp/some.file
root@host~# echo 123 >> /tmp/some.file
-bash: /tmp/some.file: Permission denied
```

если запустить `/bin/sh` (на самом деле это `/bin/dash`), сообщение выглядит чуть иначе:

```
sh: 1: cannot create /tmp/some.file: Permission denied
```

происходит такое чудо, если файл создан в каталоге, принадлежащем root-у и имеющем набор прав `ugo=rwx,o+t` (обычно такой набор прав у каталогов `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` и т.п., но можно создать каталог с такой принадлежностью и правами в любом другом месте — поведение будет идентичное).

наблюдается в *ubuntu* версии 20.04 (программа *linux* версии 5.4.0, библитотека *glibc* версии 2.31).

apparmor, selinux — отсутствуют.

кто виновник такого поведения и где оно задокументировано? версии предполагаемых кандидатов (ubuntu, linux, glibc) я привёл, но, возможно, виноват кто-то ещё.

Comment: что-то нашлось: https://askubuntu.com/q/1250974/416190

Comment: https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=50147 Вот тут про это подробно

Comment: @Namerek, спасибо, про главного виновника я и не подумал. да, systemd — отличная операционная система, в которой не хватает лишь нормального менеджера загрузки.

Comment: У меня подобный случай есть. Примонтированна nfs. Под юзером пишу(постгрес xlog) в неё файлы - пытаюсь дописать рутом - пермишн денаед на весь каталог, даже чмод 777 не помогает)

Comment: @eri, можно отключить эту опцию (см. ссылку в первом комментарии) или переместить файл в подкаталог или поменять владельца файла перед записью.

Comment: А причём тут `systemd`? Это поведение ядра, которое включается через указанные поля. Там даже версия ядра написана.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> кто виновник такого поведения и где оно задокументировано?

виновник — комплект программ под общим названием *systemd*.

начиная с версии 241 при загрузке по умолчанию включается параметр программы *linux* `/proc/sys/fs/protected_regular` (доступен начиная с версии 4.19 этой программы).

благодаря чему программа *linux* блокирует запись в файлы при выполнении определённых условий:

1. при вызове функции `open()` передаётся флаг `O_CREAT`
2. файл принадлежит другому пользователю (не тому, кто пытается осуществить запись)
3. файл находится непосредственно в каталоге:

   1. который доступен для записи всем пользователям
   2. у которого установлен «sticky bit» («restricted deletion flag»)
   3. владелец которого не совпадает с владельцем файла

каталогами, отвечающими условиям 3.1 и 3.2, по умолчанию являются такие каталоги как `/tmp` и `/var/tmp`.

---

возможные пути «обхода» этого ограничения:

- отключить параметр (плохое решение):

  ```
  $ sudo sysctl fs.protected_regular=0
  ```
- создавать файл в каталоге, не отвечающем условиям 3.1 и 3.2. например, в подкаталоге, созданном в каталоге `/tmp`.

---

ссылки:

- [коммит, включающий упомянутый параметр](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/2732587540035227fe59e4b64b60127352611b35)
- [коммит, добавивший упомянутый параметр программе *linux*](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=30aba6656f61ed44cba445a3c0d38b296fa9e8f5)
- новость: [выпуск системного менеджера systemd 241](https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=50147)