Недостаточно прав для записи в файл
Возникла проблема с записью в файл в папке tmp.
От пользователя steam создан файл, выданы права o+rwx, но возникает Permission denied при записи в файл от пользователя test
У каталога права rwxrwxrwt.
У файла права -rw-rw-rwx.
Если убрать sticky bit у каталога tmp. То проблема проходит. Не могу понять как это связано, ведь sticky bit на каталоге защищает файл от удаления другим пользователем, а в данном случае я модифицирую файл.
Почему sticky bit на каталоге не дает модифицировать файл в этом каталоге?

посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1154434/501383 --- похоже это ваш случай
